# Comments page id wp_list_comments

Tags: comments, comments-template, paginate-comments-links

Under post i want to display last five comments. At next comment page or after click button "show more comments" I want to display all comments or set quantity comments to display. How can i do it? There is any variable like "comment_page_id" ? Thanks

Comment: A good search phrase for your needs would be: "wordpress comment pagination."

Comment: Still i cant found anything useless :(